# Error in using Recommenderlab package in R

Tags: r, recommendation-engine

I am getting an error trying to use the recommenderlab package in R.

Basically when I am trying to run the collaborative model creation, I am getting an error.

Here are the steps I did

```
library("recommenderlab")        
# Loading to pre-computed affinity data  
affinity.data<-read.csv("collected_data.csv")
affinity.matrix<- as(affinity.data,"realRatingMatrix")
# Creation of the model - U(ser) B(ased) C(ollaborative) F(iltering)
Rec.model<-Recommender(affinity.matrix[1:5000], method = "UBCF")
```

In the last step I am getting an error saying

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘Recommender’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’

Has anyone used recommenderlab package and gotten this error? Please help.

Thanks

Comment: From `?realRatingMatrix`: `signature(from = "data.frame", to = "realRatingMatrix"): coercion from a data.frame with three columns. Col 1 contains user ids, col 2 contains item ids and col 3 contains ratings.`  It is likely that your data.frame does not have the correct structure, but without a reproducible example it is impossible to tell.  Please include a representative data set for affinity.data or at least `str(affinity.data)`

Comment: I have the same problem, what could help in avoiding the error?: > str(affinity.data) 
'data.frame': 9835 obs. of  169 variables:
 $ citrus.fruit             : int  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ semi.finished.bread      : int  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ margarine                : int  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ready.soups              : int  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

Comment: Hello, where do you get the data "collected_data.csv"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem too, and in my case I converted the data into transactions and then to binaryRatingMatrix, example:

**Convert data.frame in to transactions:**

```
movies2 <- as(movies, "transactions")
```

**Convert to binaryRatingMatrix:**

```
movies3 <- as(movies2, "binaryRatingMatrix")
```